# How to unlock Android Phone programmatically when I have set password/lock pattern enabled in phone settings?

Tags: android

I try to use the following code to unlock screen, it works well in my Android 2.3.6 mobile phone only if there is no password/lock pattern enabled in phone settings.

If I enable password/lock pattern in my Android 2.3.6 mobile phone settings, the code will cause phone to display password/lock pattern screen, I have to input password or draw pattern manually to unlock screen.

I hope to unlock screen automatically when I have set password/lock pattern enabled in phone settings, how can I do? Thanks!

```
private void UnLock(){   

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                     | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                                     | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();    


    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
    final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock"); 
    kl.disableKeyguard();       

}
```

**BTW, I test the code above in Android 4.2.2 mobile phone, the srceen can be unlocked automatically even if I enable password/lock pattern in the phone settings, I don't know why.**

Comment: Would be a bit of a security breach don't you think? Imagine that every app on your device can unlock your device...

Comment: Even if it was possible, this would be bad practice due to the security risks involved.

Comment: Thanks! But I find some apps can do that, how can these apps do that?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.skiplock
and   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benhirashima.unlockwithwifitrial

Comment: My guess would be that SkipLock acheives this effect by changing the system setting for lockscreen to and from the configured Lock based on the context, rather than actually performing the unlock.