# How can I cancel screen lock with a password programmatically?

Tags: android

I have read the documnet [How can i set up screen lock with a password programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically).

I can set a password to lock the screen programmatically using the following code.

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager =(DevicePolicyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName demoDeviceAdmin =new ComponentName(this, MyAdmin.class);

devicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(demoDeviceAdmin,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(demoDeviceAdmin, 5);

boolean result = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("123456", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);

Toast.makeText(this, "button_lock_password_device..."+result,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

How can I cancel screen lock with a password programmatically? Could you help me?

And more, how can I set up screen lock with a PIN programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give me some siggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** How can I cancel screen lock with a password programmatically?

**A:**

```
devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(compName, 0);
boolean result = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
```

**Q:** How can I set up screen lock with a PIN programmatically

**A:** Your app has to be approved by the user as a `Device Administrator`. For that you have to add `DeviceAdminReceiver`, for that you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html)

P.S. For being admin app, user must have to go to Settings screen and accept you app as Admin.

Comment: Thanks! To Murtaza Hussain: The code boolean result = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE..  works well both android 4.1.2 and android 2.3.6, but It can't work under android 5.0. So I think I should change the lock screen type from Password lock to Swipe lock or None lock programmatically to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why you did not create your own lock/unlock code?

You can lock/unlock screen as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14352648/1043882).What remains,is getting password.To do that,use `sharedpreferences` to save password and when user turn screen on,you only have to get password and compare it with saved password.

Comment: Thanks!

I have read both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723185/android-screen-lock-unlock-programatically/12723269#12723269.

If you have locked a phone with passsword, sometimes you can't cancel it simply, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042562/how-to-unlock-android-phone-programmatically-when-i-have-set-password-lock-patte.

Comment: So I hope that I can change the lock screen type from Password lock to Swipe lock programmatically, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193714/how-to-change-the-lock-screen-type-from-password-lock-to-swipe-lock-programmatic