# Can the android application access the screen lock?

Tags: android

I have an idea to make an application that, depending on the time, will put another password on the phone. Let's say the user has a password on the screen "777" and if on the clock is 22:22 or 15:15, the application will not accept the usual password, but will request another "555". Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Check this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166217/how-can-i-cancel-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically

Comment: I was reading a little beyond and it seems to be unable since marshmallow policies on device administrator, good luck