# How to open camera when the screen is locked by password/pattern?

Tags: android, camera, android-widget, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using camera2API for my camera app. It worked well without error with swipe mode (no security). However, it has a critical issue which cannot open camera when the screen is lock by password or pattern. The error is that I cannot open camera in that lock modes. I tried some way to unlock (by code) the phone before open camera but it does not work. I do not know why the Android 6.0, the default camera app can open camera in the modes by double pressing the home button. Is it possible to open camera in the modes in Android L (5.0) by code? Thank all

This is my code to open the screen

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_activity_unlock);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i think double button press to open camera is supported by the ROM(aka OS) not the app itself. If you set your app for default camera app- then double pressing the home will open it

Comment: But Smart Lock does not need ROM. Some device which registered with smartLock can open, although the screen is locked by password or pattern

Comment: Smart Lock just unlocks the phone if some secured limitation is met- For example bluetooth device/ you are at pre-set location. I believe you cant just make your app unlock the phone. If you have some sort of Smart Lock set, and try your code it should work

Comment: Sorry. I did not figure out what your solution. In case of my question, the screen is off with pattern lock, how can I open my camera app in that situation. For example, I can use a timer to call my camera activity.

Comment: I think there is no solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042562/how-to-unlock-android-phone-programmatically-when-i-have-set-password-lock-patte